# How to convert mkv file to mp4 with subtitles and changing DTS audio to AAC or AC3?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, conversion

I have some MKV files that I would like to copy to my PS3, so I have to convert them.

Someone told me the easiest way without losing quality would be with ffmpeg.

However, I want them to have subtitles and when I use:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4
```

…they don't appear in my PS3.

Furthermore, some files have DTS audio - how can I convert them so I have audio in my PS3?

Is it possible to do everything with ffmpeg?

And one of my files, when I converted it, it ran too slowly in my PS3 as if it was in slow motion - Can I do anything to change that? Also, the subtitles are "inside" the MKV file. Do I need to do something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-acodec copy` implies that you maintain the audio codec. Also, if your PS3 cannot keep up with the video codec, I would recommend converting everything.

The loss of quality in the conversion is usually negligible for video playback.

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:v 35M -b:a 224k out.mp4
```

NOTE this values are quite high to start, so you could try lowering them if the file size is too much: 35M for 1080p, 15M for 720p, 5M for 480p

Comment: I recommend against using `libvo_aacenc`. Rather use `-c:a aac -strict experimental` – it offers better quality. Also, your command will not move over the subtitles to the MP4. You need to add `-c:s mov_text`. Finally, I wouldn't set a fixed bitrate, but rather set the `-crf` value to something appropriate. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264